# React Native: Render HTML in View

Tags: html, react-native

I have a React Native app which is receiving an `HTML` file from the **backend**. This is the content of the HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #wrapper {
        // styling
      }
      .child {
        // styling
      }
      #img {
        // styling
      }
      #desc {
        // styling
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="img" class="child"></div>
      <div id="desc" class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    const img = document.getElementById("img");

    img.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // logic
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

I just want to display this HTML in a react-native view along with both it's `style` as well `script` tag.

Answer (score 1):

you should use some sort of prebuilt library for that...

here's the one I found really useful => https://github.com/archriss/react-native-render-html

Comment: HI, I don't find any way that I can pass script along with HTML, as you can I'm doing DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I used React-native-render-html library to render html and it works great
versatile and very easy to use, you can het it from

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html

Comment: HI, I don't find any way that I can pass script along with HTML, as you can I'm doing DOM manipulation.